# Why does Wald's confidence interval use a quantile from the normal distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval

We are thought in basic statistics that when population variance is unknown, use a t-quantile instead of a normal quantile when calculating confidence intervals.

However, why does this logic then not apply to Wald's confidence interval, which uses a normal quantile (typically 1.96)?

Comment: ... because it's using an asymptotic result

Comment: So what? Yes, it's an asymptotic result, which we use to form confidence intervals in the usual way that we do for standard normals. And I am saying that the "usual way" is to use the t-quantile. Which we don't for the Wald test.

Comment: The t-quantiles are used when there's a pivotal quantity with a t-distribution. We don't have one of those here, nor any argument that the t-quantile will be a better approximation than the normal quantile.  Why would you use a t in this instance? The expectation you suggest in comments (but don't state in the question), with the reasoning behind it, might be best placed in your question so it could be addressed in an answer.